# dart: replacing ViewChildren by queries

Tags: inheritance, angular, dart, components, viewchild

I know that I could use the `@ViewChildren` annotation to access DOM elements. But, in this particular case, the `entries` property is defined in the ancestor component (`MenuComp`). So I tried to use the `queries` property, as follows:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '''
    <ul>
      <subentry-comp #entries *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></subentry-comp>
    </ul>''',
    inputs: const <String>['items'],
    queries: const <String, dynamic>{'entries': const ViewChildren('entries')})
class SubmenuComp extends MenuComp {}
```

But `entries` is still null. Am I using the `queries` property in a wrong way?

Comment: Never seen `quieries` ind `@Component()` mentioned before. I knew about the `@Query()` annotation for constructor parameters but it is deprecated for as long as I used Angular2 (since late alpha). Your query seems to query elements from the template. I don't understand how this relates to "ancestors"

Comment: AFAIK `@ViewChild(ren)` and `@ContentChild(ren)` are built on top of `@Query` and I wouldn't expect `@Query` to do something substantial different.

Answer (score 1):

As of angular 4.0.0-alpha+1 it will inherit the annotation from the parent if you use `@ViewChildren` on the field in the parent class. The `queries` argument to `Component` will be going away.